# How to disable "warning: Found unknown command" in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I'd like to avoid getting this annoying:

```
Generating docs for compound bla_param...
/home/mathieu/Projects/bla_parser.h:57: warning: Found unknown command `\0'
/home/mathieu/Projects/bla_parser.h:57: warning: Found unknown command `\0'
```

The only option I can think of is a double escaping, and have:

```
/** Query parameters */
typedef struct bla_param{
  char *cclose;                               /**< list of params, separated by '\\0' */
```

But this make my code difficult to read, and add extra work to developers when documenting the API...

Any other solution I did not think of ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of Doxygen may address this issue. I was able to reproduce this warning with Doxygen 1.6.2, but it didn't occur in later versions (I tested 1.7.6.1, 1.8.0 and 1.8.2).

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.6 still makes "Found unknown command `\notest'" if I have a line that look like "\notest blah blah"